# 0xc0000225 error after imaging, but still works

Tags: windows-7, windows, acronis-trueimage

I have three identical systems: HP Z440 with a 128 GB SSD drive running Windows 7 Pro x64. I think they're set up as AHCI. Computer 1 and computer 2 both had SSD drive failures. HP support came out and replaced computer 1 and computer 2 each, with a brand new 128 GB SSD drive.

I booted into the working computer 3 with Acronis True Image 2016 and took a full disk image and put the image on a shared drive. I then booted into computer 1 and computer 2 and restored computer 3's image onto computer 1 and computer 2.

Now both computer 1 and computer 2 have the same exact problem. They boot up and stop at this error:

> Title: Windows Boot Manager
>   Status: 0xc0000225
>   Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible

At the bottom of the screen it gives me the option to press ENTER=continue. When I press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it boots into Windows correctly and works just fine. If I reboot the computer it goes back into this screen. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, Windows works fine.

The only thing I tried is Windows Repair disk. After I boot into it, it gives me an error, so I can't continue with a disk repair:

> **System Recovery Options**
>   This version of System Recovery Options is not compatible
>   with the version of Windows you are trying to repair. 
>   Try using a recovery disc that is compatible
>   with this version of Windows.
>   <sub>(Manually transcribed)</sub>

[image: system repair error]

I use Acronis True Image 2016 all of the time on Supermicro and other HP systems and never had this problem. What is actually causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: @MJH: When you edit in an image, please do it the way I have done it in this post, especially if the image is wider than 600 pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by disabling all possible startup devices other than legacy hard drive in the Boot Order section of the BIOS. I think the issue occurred because originally the HP was set to boot from a UEFI partition that was destroyed in the image restore (image was from a different computer).